# Calling a template in C++

Tags: c++, xcode

First of all I must say I am giving my first steps into C++ and I came from PHP so excuse this basic question. I been looking and testing many alternatives and I cannot seem to understand how to do this which in PHP would be something like `distance($str1, $str2)` in order to read whatever the function `distance` returns.

What I am trying to do is call a template which should return the Levenshtein distance between 2 strings.

Here is my code

```
template <class T> unsigned int edit_distance(const T& s1, const T& s2)
{
    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    vector<vector<unsigned int> > d(len1 + 1, vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));

    d[0][0] = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) d[i][0] = i;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len2; ++i) d[0][i] = i;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i)
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j)

            d[i][j] = std::min( std::min(d[i - 1][j] + 1,d[i][j - 1] + 1),
                               d[i - 1][j - 1] + (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1) );
    return d[len1][len2];
}

string text1="house";
string text2="houses";
edit_distance <int> (text1, text2);
```

The problem is on line `edit_distance <int> (text1, text2);` and the error Xcode is giving is: `C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations`

Again, I know this must be really basic, but I can not find the proper way of doing it.
Any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't call a template. You instantiate it, and you might call some member function (or static function) of that particular instantiation. Template can be understood as a way to generate (thru instantiation) some code. They are not called.

Comment: Why `<int>`, when the input are strings?

Comment: Thanks Basile for the correction. In this case I am trying to call edit_distance. 
As what `edit_distance` returns is an integer I thought I should call it with `<int>` but yet again, this are my very fist steps with C++ so I am most probably wrong. Also when using `string` the build fails with the same error

Comment: @Jim - If this is your real code, the first problem is that you try to call something outside of a function. In C++, the execution starts inside the `main()` function - where is it?

Comment: Thanks Bo, and sorry for not clarifying that. This is just part of a bigger code, the rest of my code compiles well, also when I comment out the `edit_distance` line it compiles.The issue I am sure is that I don't know how to get the returns of `edit_distance`

Comment: But it compiles after replacing `int` with `string`: http://ideone.com/FFxPP

Comment: Thanks @Lol4t0 after looking at your example in combination with Bo question I got the answer. I though Bo was asking if I had a main() function which I did, what I did not knew was that contrary to what happens with PHP, the code outside the main function was not executed or produced an error. It will take me a long way to go to C ++ from PHP I guess... anyway THANKS a lot for all the quick help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test a suspision of mine I took your code, added the minimal includes and using declarations to allow the compiler to get to the call to `edit_distance` and compiled it. Here is the complete contents of the file I compiled:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using std::vector;
using std::string;

template <class T> unsigned int edit_distance(const T& s1, const T& s2)
{
    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    vector<vector<unsigned int> > d(len1 + 1, vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));

    d[0][0] = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) d[i][0] = i;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len2; ++i) d[0][i] = i;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i)
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j)

            d[i][j] = std::min( std::min(d[i - 1][j] + 1,d[i][j - 1] + 1),
                               d[i - 1][j - 1] + (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1) );
    return d[len1][len2];
}

string text1="house";
string text2="houses";
edit_distance <int> (text1, text2);
```

And my suspision checked out; I got the following error:

```
main.cpp:26:22: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
edit_distance <int> (text1, text2);
                     ^~~~~
```

This is the exact error you mention, therefore I believe it's very likely you've made the same mistake as I included in my test source code. Most experienced programmers would just assume that your incomplete code is shown as it is for brevity, and would automatically insert some surrounding code that would completely avoid this error.

---

The thing you have not understood seems to be that in C++ code does not just go anywhere. C++ programs are not simply a series of statements that get executed as an interpreter reads them in the source.

C++ is a compiled language. The program is a series of declarations and definitions of functions, classes, etc. Statements, i.e. code that does stuff, goes only inside definitions. Your function call `edit_distance<int>(text1, text2);` is not inside any definition, and therefore the compiler is not expecting a statement and has no idea what you're saying. So put it inside a definition. You probably want to use a function definition:

```
void foo() {
    string text1="house";
    string text2="houses";
    edit_distance <int> (text1, text2);
}
```

Also, when the compiled code is executed the execution begins in a special entry point function, main. Only the code that is reachable through this entry point ever gets executed. (actually this isn't really true, but the other cases are irrelevant at the moment.)

Therefore, you need a main function that eventually leads to the code you want to execute. You could have `main` call the above `foo`, or you could just put your code directly in `main`:

```
int main() {
    string text1="house";
    string text2="houses";
    edit_distance <int> (text1, text2);
}
```

This code will still not compile, because the `<int>` part is incorrect. The type inside the angle brackets becomes the type assigned to `T` in the edit_distance function template:

```
template <class T> unsigned int edit_distance(const T& s1, const T& s2)
```

`edit_distance<int>` says to set T equal to int:

```
unsigned int edit_distance(const int& s1, const int& s2)
```

And that's not what you want. You probably want to set T equal to string so that the s1 and s2 parameters are strings.

```
int main() {
    string text1="house";
    string text2="houses";
    edit_distance<string>(text1,text2);
}
```

Next you probably want to actually see the return value. Add `#include <iostream>` at the beginning of the source with your other includes, and then use the main function:

```
int main() {
    string text1="house";
    string text2="houses";
    std::cout << edit_distance<string>(text1,text2) << '\n';
}
```

[Complete, compilable program](http://ideone.com/QAPqf)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and explanation, this helps me a lot! and yes, I was not aware of how things get compiled in C++ which seems to be really different for what happens in PHP. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In

```
template <class T> unsigned int edit_distance(const T& s1, const T& s2)
```

the type T can be inferred directly from the arguments. So there's no need to specify the type at all. Just call

```
edit_distance(text1, text2);
```

from within a function. You can do this for any type supported by the template. If the type isn't supported, you'll get a compile-time error.

You need to explicitly specify a type only if it can't be inferred. And in your case, the type you specified, `<int>`, didn't match the arguments you provided.

Comment: Thanks Jon, as you said, the problem was that I was calling from outside a function (bad PHP habits), now I learned. Thanks again for your time.